# django url encode issue in using mathjax

Tags: django, encode, mathjax

I wanna add mathjax script into my template

`</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "MathJax-2.4-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full.js" %}"></script>`

But django encode '?' to '%3F' and '=' to '%3D'(In firefox console), So I get a incorrect url. If I use "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
as my "src" attribution value, it's correct. And firefix console can show '?' and '=' correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved the problem myself. It should place "?config=xxx" out of "%}". It looks like

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "MathJax-2.4-latest/MathJax.js" %}?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full">
</script>`